# Stop the Banner and Profile picture get change on MouseOver

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC project which has a Banner in _Layout.cshtml

```
<img src="../../SitePics/NewBanner.jpg") class="BannerSize" />
```

and a Img tag to get the Profile Pic according to the currect logges user

```
<img src="../../@Model.TripPic" class="TripImage" align="left" />
```

and I have implemented Rating with Jason

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4a2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

          $(function () {
        $("img").mouseover(function () {
            giveRating($(this), "FilledStar.png");
            $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
        });

        $("img").mouseout(function () {
            giveRating($(this), "EmptyStar.png");
        });

        $("img").click(function () {
            $("img").unbind("mouseout mouseover click");

            // call ajax methods to update database
            var url = "/Rating/PostRating?rating=" + parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
            $.post(url, null, function (data) {
                $("#result").text(data);
            });
        });
    });

    function giveRating(img, image) {
        img.attr("src", "/Content/Images/" + image)
           .prevAll("img").attr("src", "/Content/Images/" + image);
    }
</script>        

 <p>
    <img src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="1" />
    <img src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="2" />
    <img src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="3" />
    <img src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="4" />
    <img src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="5" />
</p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

My Issue Is whe I run the Program My Banner and Profile picture also get changed into Empty or Filled Starts when it runs over/Out mouse pointer..

Please help me to stop the Banner and Profile picture get change on MouseOver

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer :**

Add a class to the images for rating, say a class "rating" and then replace $("img") with  `$("img.rating")`

**Long Answer :**

Ok, the jquery selector you are using is this `$("img")` which says select all `images` from the page. Hence the problem.

Now what you should do,

As you want to have the jquery run only for the 5 Rating images, you can have all the images have a common class like as shown below..

```
<img class="Rating" src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="1" />
<img class="Rating" src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="2" />
<img class="Rating" src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="3" />
<img class="Rating" src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="4" />
<img class="Rating" src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="5" />
```

and Now you can use your code like this...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

          $(function () {
        $("img.rating").mouseover(function () {
            giveRating($(this), "FilledStar.png");
            $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
        });

        $("img.rating").mouseout(function () {
            giveRating($(this), "EmptyStar.png");
        });

        $("img.rating").click(function () {
            $("img.rating").unbind("mouseout mouseover click");

            // call ajax methods to update database
            var url = "/Rating/PostRating?rating=" + parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
            $.post(url, null, function (data) {
                $("#result").text(data);
            });
        });
    });

    function giveRating(img, image) {
        img.attr("src", "/Content/Images/" + image)
           .prevAll("img").attr("src", "/Content/Images/" + image);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant..... Thanks a lot Yasser... Code required a bit fixes but thanks to u now its working. Bellow I have given the working code.. its almost the same code u hv corrected for me but with capital letters in necessary places.

```
<script>

$(function () {
    $("img.Rating").mouseover(function () {
        giveRating($(this), "FilledStar.png");
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    });

    $("img.Rating").mouseout(function () {
        giveRating($(this), "EmptyStar.png");
    });

    $("img.Rating").click(function () {
        $("img.Rating").unbind("mouseout mouseover click");

        // call ajax methods to update database
        var url = "/Rating/PostRating?rating=" + parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
        $.post(url, null, function (data) {
            $("#result").text(data);
        });
    });
});

function giveRating(img, image) {
    img.attr("src", "/Content/Images/" + image)
       .prevAll("img.Rating").attr("src", "/Content/Images/" + image);
}

</script>        

 <p>
    <img class="Rating" src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="1" />
    <img class="Rating" src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="2" />
    <img class="Rating" src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="3" />
    <img class="Rating" src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="4" />
    <img class="Rating" src="../../Content/Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="5" />
</p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Yahooo .. Thanks a lot

Comment: m Glad I could help, and yes Welcome to Stack Oveflow ! :)